# Unity 2022.2.0b1 get IP of device

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I wonder what code i can use to get the IP of the player in my Unity game for mobile (IOS and Android) in the Unity 2022.2.0b1 using C#.

Have been looking up here on other questions, but they seems outdated.

Comment: Call out to a service that returns the user's IP address. I'm pretty sure that's what the other questions will have offered up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for my issue, if anyone else has this issue in Unity 2022 this code can be used to obtain IP of the player

```
public string getIP()
{
    string userIP = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://icanhazip.com/");
    return userIP;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using UnityEngine;

public class DeviceIPManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new System.Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this, but it only gave me the local IP address, which is not what i am looking for. However, i am deploying my own IP API, so i guess i will be fine going that way, however the best solution to get the IP is to use a web API i would guess, for those who are looking for a solution.